# openERP dynamic form via wizard

Tags: odoo

I'm relatively new to OpenERP development but I think I can gain much understanding if I could get a rough example of how to do the following (in OpenERP version 7):

I created a wizard.
In a view I have a button to open the wizard form:

This opens up correctly the window (dialog) and I can call methods to do stuff from buttons within 
this wizard form defined in the wizard object.

I want to be able to populate the form view dynamically using records from another model (and then do other stuff upon saving form).

For example in "purchase orders" and for a specific purchase order, I want to get all the products linked to this purchase order (that would be displayed in the tree view).

If I have the button (to launch window/dialog form) placed within the view of the purchase order, the main thing I would like to be able to do is populate the form for the given purchase order with the products for this purchase order.

**My question is how do I instantiate the wizard form with the id of the current purchase order, then access the product items for this purchase order.**

I've looked into other examples but with older version of OpenERP.

Any help/pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you button is of type action, then you will be able to get the id of the purchase order(model from where the button action is calling) from context['active_id']. if your button is of type object, then in the button function specify the context['active_id']= id of the purchase order.
then use the default_get() to populate the data to your wizard.

Answer (score 1):

A simple pointer would be buttons on partner screen like Quotation, Invoice, Meeting etc.